# Warning: fread() [function.fread]: Length parameter must be greater than 0

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a site hosted with 1and1 - who are useless! For some reason the backup scripts they provide no longer work and they can't provide me with an answer! So I thought I'd write my own, this is my code:

```
  if (file_exists('backupfile.sql')){

 $FP = fopen ( 'backupfile.sql', 'r' );
 $READ = fread ( $FP, filesize ( 'backupfile.sql') );
 $READ = explode ( ";\n", $READ );

 foreach ( $READ AS $RED )
 {
  mysql_query ( $RED );
 }

  echo 'Done'; 
 }else{
  echo "no file";
 }
```

however this gives me the following error

```
Warning: fread() [function.fread]: Length parameter must be greater than 0
```

if I put an @ infront of the fread the script doesn't error but it doesn't perform the backup.

Comment: i think your file can not be opened(wrong path, permissions). You should test if($FP){ ... }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... My guess from the error message would be that `backupfile.sql` is empty. Therefore, `fread()` can't read anything from it.

Comment: @Mike what do you mean by "written to the file"? Where are you writing stuff?

Comment: I'#ve realised what was wrong with my code, sorry I missed out a large chunk of another function - thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
filesize ( 'backupfile.sql')
```

is not giving you a filesize, try putting in the full path to the file, also make sure PHP has permission to read the file.

edit: you can use [is_readable()](http://php.net/is_readable) to test if the file can be read

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify a max read size when using fread. that indicates that it thinks your filesize is 0. try using FILE instead since it's a local file and all...

```
if (file_exists('backupfile.sql')){

 $READ = file( 'backupfile.sql');

 foreach ( $READ AS $RED )
 {
  mysql_query ( $RED );
 }

  echo 'Done'; 
 }else{
  echo "no file";
 }
```